# Como puedo comparar un nodo con un if para así mostrar los que superen un valor determinado en C++

Tags: c++

Llevo días practicando y haciendo este ejercicio y todavía no lo entiendo del todo, incluso hasta medio entiendo mi código a pesar de estar estudiándolo día tras día.

Sucede que para terminarlo tengo que hacer un método que muestre todos los nodos que superen un valor determinado. El problema es que no sé como hacerlo, llevo muchos intentos y aun no encuentro la solución y creo que me confundí totalmente con el tema de punteros y listas.

Bueno, espero puedan ayudarme Este es el código del método hasta donde he llegado.

Código:

```
void Lista::mostrarNodos(Lista *lista){
    Lista *actual=new Lista();
    actual=lista;
    int opcion, valor;
    
    while(opcion!=0){
        cout<<"\t.:MENU:.\n";
        cout<<"1. Insertar valor manualmente\n";
        cout<<"2. Generar valor aleatoriamente\n";
        cout<<"0. Salir\n";
        cout<<"Opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        system("cls");
        
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                cout<<"Digite el valor: ";
                cin>>valor;
                system("cls");
                cout<<"Valor digitado: "<<valor<<endl;
                while(actual!=NULL){
                    if(actual>=valor){
                        cout<<actual->dato<<" -> ";
                        actual=actual->siguiente;
                    }
                }
            case 2:
                srand(time(NULL));
                valor = 1 + rand() % (100); 
                cout<<"Valor generado: "<<valor<<endl;
                while(actual!=NULL){
                    if(actual>=valor){
                        cout<<actual->dato<<" -> ";
                        actual=actual->siguiente;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    while(actual!=NULL){
        cout<<actual->dato<<" -> ";
        actual=actual->siguiente;
    }
}
```

Comment: En primer lugar te faltan los *break* de los *switch case*, de lo contrario el caso uno se irá hasta el caso 2.

Answer (score 0):

En la pregunta hay detalles importantes que no se mencionan y como estás confundido no sería de mucha ayuda preguntarte por ellos. Así que la respuesta tiene el objetivo de orientarte un poco.

---

En primer lugar, veo un método de la clase Lista y por algún extraño motivo quieres crear una lista nueva ahí:

```
void Lista::mostrarNodos(Lista *lista){
    Lista *actual=new Lista();
    actual=lista;
    int opcion, valor;
```

Esa no es la mejor forma de usar POO. Un objeto tiene que ser responsable de sí mismo, no de otros objetos. Solucionemos eso.

Para eso antes necesitas una clase **Nodo** y una clase **Lista** que se verán más o menos así:

```
class Nodo {
    int valor;
    Nodo* siguiente;
}

class Lista {
    Nodo* primerNodo = nullptr;

public:
    ~Lista(){
        eliminarTodos();
    }

    void crearUltimo(int valor);
    void eliminarUltimo();
    void eliminarTodos();

    int leerPosicion(int posicion);
    void imprimir();
}
```

De esta forma, quien use la clase `Lista` no tiene que conocer los detalles de la implementación.

**Importante**: la idea es que las funciones `eliminar` se encarguen también de liberar la memoria y `crear` de reservarla.

---

Ahora lo que nos interesa, la función `imprimirLista` debe limitarse a un único propósito y no debe recibir ningún puntero ni crear ninguna lista dentro. Por lo tanto su implementación se vería así:

```
void Lista::imprimir(){
    for (Nodo* actual = primero; actual != nullptr; actual = actual->siguiente){
        cout << actual->valor << ", ";
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Con pequeñas modificaciones a esta función puedes mostrar solo ciertos elementos como pides en el título de la pregunta.

---

El resto de tu código que estaba ahí hay que ponerlo en un mejor lugar.

Sugiero que lo hagas en la función `main` u otra nueva. Además de extraer funciones para facilitar su lectura. Así:

```
int agregarAleatorio(Lista& lista){
    int valor = 1 + rand() % (100); 
    cout << "Valor generado: " << valor << '\n';
    lista.crearUltimo(valor);
}

void agregarManual(Lista& lista){
    int valor = 0;
    cout<<"Digite el valor: ";
    cin>>valor;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Valor digitado: " << valor << '\n';
    lista.crearUltimo(valor);
}

int main() {
    int opcion = -1;
    Lista lista;
    // Darle una semilla a rand
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    while(opcion!=0){
        cout<<"\t.:MENU:.\n";
        cout<<"1. Insertar valor manualmente\n";
        cout<<"2. Generar valor aleatoriamente\n";
        cout<<"0. Salir\n";
        cout<<"Opcion: ";
        cin>>opcion;
        system("cls");
        
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:
                agregarManual(lista);
                break;
            case 2:
                agregarAleatorio(lista);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Por cierto, te faltaban los `break` en los case del `switch`.

Te dejo la tarea de implementar las otras funciones que necesites y crear otras que también te sean útiles siguiendo la misma filosofía.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, aunque a la final este ejercicio es viejo, logre arreglarmelas para resolverlo, y también me di cuenta que el codigo que coloque aquí, por alguna extraña razón se copio incompleto y con algunas cosas faltantes, aun no comprendo muy bien el tema, pero al leerlo medio me oriento un poco mas en cuanto a las listas, lo leeré con más detalle en otro momento, gracias nuevamente